# GoodFeatureToTrackDetector gives inconsistent time results - opencv

Tags: opencv

I am comparing the performance of feature detectors provided by OpenCV2.2 as basis for visual feature matching. Mainly FAST and GFTT

I am using GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector of openCV2.2 to extract corner points from set of images. I am monitoring time and speed per keypoint. The problem is that detect function time differs from run to other for same images data base. Even running it with debug and break points differ in time [using debug is faster!]

Sometimes it works really fast and other doesn't.

I am using VS2010.